# EWS: Exchange Items not available right after Update

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

I'm working on a project to sync calendar items from specific Exchange users to another application and back. In the other application there are meetings, too. My problem in several parts of my project is that I want to add attendees to the appointment, then get the appointment with the credentials of the attendee and accept it. But when I want to check bind the new appointment immediatly after updating the appointment there is no Item with the iCalUid in the folder. When I wait 2000ms after updating the meeting request is there but I don't think this is best practice. I have a short code sample:

```
string attendeeAddress = "mymailaddress";
        ExchangeService service =
            new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013)
            {
                Url = new Uri("https://exchange.sample.de/EWS/Exchange.asmx"),
                Credentials = new WebCredentials("username", "password", "domain")
            };
        Appointment app = Appointment.Bind(service, id);
        app.RequiredAttendees.Add(attendeeAddress);
        app.IsResponseRequested = false;
        app.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve);
        CalendarView view = new CalendarView(app.Start, app.End);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        FindItemsResults<Appointment> attendeeApps =
            serviceAttendee.FindAppointments(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, view);
        Appointment appAttendee;
        foreach (Appointment a in attendeeApps)
        {
            if (a.ICalUid.Equals(app.ICalUid))
            {
                appAttendee = Appointment.Bind(serviceAttendee, a.Id);
            }
        }
        appAttendee.Accept(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of what your doing your adding an attendee to a meeting and then connecting to the attendees Mailbox to accept that meeting ? If that's the case on the backend this is going to produce a Meeting Invitation that will need to be sent via Email and routed to the Attendees Mailbox via the Hub Transport Role. Even if all the recipients and server roles are on the same server you will need to allow time for the message to be delivered to the Attendees Mailbox this is just the normal way Exchange handles Meeting for local (or remote attendees) it will never be instant as Exchange stores each copy of the Appointment as a separate store Item.

Comment: Ok but how schould I do that? I don't think that waiting two seconds is the best thing I can do because when it takes longer than two seconds it crashes again. Is there any way to wait for the new item?

Comment: Your code crashing is on you and can be easily resolved just be followings best coding practice around exceptions. You can look at subscribing or polling the folder in question with EWS. The other thing to keep in mind is that meeting invites aren't user specific so you can accept any copy of an invite e.g. from the sentitems folder of the organizer etc

Comment: I know that I can catch the Exception but I don't think that the exception should occur.  But if the meeting request is not user specific, how is it possible that some Attenddees accept it and others don't. Don't get it why I can Accept in the sent items of the organizer.

Comment: Your getting an exception because your code logic is flawed eg in the code you posted if FindItems doesn't find the appointment then attendeeApps will be null so calling the accept method will generate an exception. You should check if attendeeApps is null before calling Accept. Exchange calendaring works by sending Meeting invites to the attendees, the meeting invite in the SentItems of the org will be the same message that the attendees receive pre the Transport Role processing the Envelope recipients (but no changes are done to the message its just delivered to the recipient mailboxes).

Comment: yes I know I didn't do that here because of shorter code, but how can I alway find the Item? I know the item is there /will be there in a few seconds but at the time I call FindItems it sometimes is not there already.
Ok but when I call the Update on the organizer's appointment the Meeting Request is sent to the Attendees and a copy is saved to the organizer's sent Items folder. Now when I Update the Item of the organizer this doesn't affect the Attendees' Meeting request because these are copies. Can you give me the code how to add Attendees who accept the request automatically?